Как загрузить картинку в PREVIEW_PICTURE со внешнего источника в 1С-Битрикс?
Всем привет, делаю парсер xml, который будет добавлять элементы в инфоблоки, столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу загрузить Превью в инфоблок, аналогично в свойство с файлами, как это пофиксить, если превью лежит на внешнем источнике?
Например https://test.ru/upload/image.jpg

Видно, что в "PREVIEW_PICTURE" вроде бы все правильно, но при запуске парсера ничего не получается
Так же в инфоблоке есть свойство с дополнительными картинками, оно множественное, как туда загружать картинки?
У меня создается ассоциативный список файлов вида
array( "id свойства" =>
array(
1 => "https://test.ru/upload/img.jpeg",
2 => "https://test.tu/upload.img_2.jpeg"
)
)
Помогите пожалуства, все предоставлю!
